# How to make navigation text not overlap on second line

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styles

I have this page I am developing:

http://128.48.204.195:3000

For some reason the menu item that has two words like "SPRQL Endpoint" has the second word overlapping on the second line.

How can I make the second word stay on the same line?  This is in Firefox and here is my cs for the navigation:

```
.menusystem 

{

    position: absolute;

    font-size: 1em;

}



.menusystem ul, .menusyystem li 

{

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}

.menusystem li {

    list-style: none outside none;

}



.menusystem ul {

    list-style: none;

    -moz-border-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;

}



.menusystem ul li {

    position: relative;

    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    -moz-border-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;

}



.menusystem ul li ul {

    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    top: 1.6em;

    right: 0;

    width: 10em;



}



.menusystem li a {

    display: block;

    padding: 5px 10px;

     /* dark blue */

    border: 1px solid #2e6ea4;

    text-decoration: none;

}



.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li {

    float:right;

    width: 10em;

    margin-right:0.2em;

    text-align: center;

}



/* IE-Win (Holly hack) reads the list item line breaks, so lets hide those \*/

* html ul li { float: left; }

* html ul li a { height: 1%; }





.menusystem li:hover ul, .menusystem li.mouseHover ul { 

    display: block;

}



.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a{

    /*

    color: #fff;

    */

    color: #fff;

    /* light blue */

    background: #7ba9c9;



        font-size: 80%;

    text-shadow: none;

    -moz-border-radius: 0px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;

    border-top: 0px;

}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a{

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;

    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4;

}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.last a{

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;

        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;

}



.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.only a {

    -moz-border-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;



}



.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover {

    color: #ff0;

    background: #2e6ea4;

}



.menusystem li.main_menu_li a{

    color: #fff;



    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #668eb8, #2e6ea4 );

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#668eb8), to(#2e6ea4));

        background-color: #2e6ea4;





    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

    -moz-border-radius: 14px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;

}



.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover {

    color: #ff0;

}
```

Comment: All the answers are superb here - one is more helpful than the other!  Thanks everyone +1 each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is the following code is causing the problem

```
.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li {
    float:right;
    width: 10em;
    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

ditch the width

Comment: +1 just tested in chrome, indeed removing the width here does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Add: white-space:nowrap;

```
.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: That worked and so did @stephenmurdoch solution.  Which is the more elegant?

Comment: @GeekedOut - If you want to make sure that navigation buttons never wrap to two lines (including in print, on iPhones, tiny screens, etc), I would put `white-space: nowrap;` in there. You can still use Stephenmurdoch's solution of omitting the width. It doesn't have to be one or the other. Whether or not you specify a width is largely a function of whether you want the navigation buttons to all be the same size or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the css declaration for `.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li`. Also, you might want to increase the width of the element a bit. Maybe from 10em to 12em or 14em.

Comment: I voted up.  This was a really helpful answer since it gave more than one correct way to go.